# Invert bits of binary representation of number

Tags: c++, bitwise

This is the code I came up with.

I added comments to make the solution more verbose.

```
int findComplement(int num) {
    // b is the answer which will be returned
    int b = 0;

    // One bit will be taken at a time from num, will be inverted and stored in n for adding to result
    int n = 0;

    // k will be used to shift bit to be inserted in correct position
    int k = 0;

    while(num){
        // Invert bit of current number
        n = !(num & 1);

        // Shift the given number one bit right to accesss next bit in next iteration
        num = num >>1 ;

        // Add the inverted bit after shifting
        b = b + (n<<k);

        // Increment the number by which to shift next bit
        k++;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Is there any redundant statment in my code which can be removed? Or any other better logic to invert bits of a given integer

Comment: Are you re-inventing the binary not operator (`~`)?

Comment: I don't want to sound dumb, But honestly, I did not know that `~` operator existed which inverts all bits of a given integer.

Comment: Many easy ways.  `~num` or `-1 - num`, or `0xFFFFFFFF - num`, or `0xFFFFFFFF ^ num` or `(-1) ^ num`.  Doing it one bit at a time is most definitely the hard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int n = 0;` This initialization is not used.  It could simply be `int n;`, or could be `int n = !(num & 1);` inside the loop, to restrict the scope of `n`.

---

This loop:

```
int k = 0;
while (num) {
    ...
    k++;
}
```

could be written as:

```
for(int k = 0; num; k++) {
    ...
}
```

---

Since you are doing bit manipulation, instead of using addition, you should probably use a “binary or” operation to merge the bit into your accumulator:

```
    b = b | (n << k);
```

or simply:

```
    b |= n << k;
```

---

### Bug

You are not inverting the most significant zero bits.  Assuming an 8-bit word size, the binary compliment of 9 (`0b00001001`) should be `0b11110110`, not `0b00000110`.   And the compliment of that should return to the original number (`0b00001001`), but instead yields `0b00000001`.

---

And, as mentioned by @Martin R, you could simply `return ~num;`